# Script to Show Black Screen While Using VNC

Tags: python, c#, python-3.x, remote-desktop, vnc

When remotely accessing another machine using VNC, I want to display a black screen to the user of that machine while I work. The user should not be able to interact with the machine until I cancel the black screen.

Can someone provide a script in Python or C# to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the VNC software you use, there may be options like i.e. "Disable Local inputs" or "Blank monitor" in UltraVNC.

Comment: Can I write a script to do this?

Comment: I don't know about the scripting in Python/C#. But you can deploy UltraVNC on computers with the options I mentionned. Under Windows, you can to it through GPO or any other method. Under Linux, you can install TightVNC like this [link](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-configure-vnc-on-ubuntu-20-04-fr)

Comment: I want it programmatically without ready-made programs